# How can I use cookies after i must have logged out in selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium, cookies

Good day.
I want to know if its possible for me to still login to a particular site using the cookies in json that I downloaded from it.

I want to login even after logging out of the site, please can anybody help me? You can refer me to any article to read or any material that has something of this nature. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried loggin in first, then saving the cookie and after that you reuse this cookie to perform the actions you want?

Comment: Try looking into driver.add_cookie() if you have the json already.

Comment: Yes! I can login save the cookie and I'm able to reuse it. But the issue I'm having is if I logout, that means i can't use the cookie again. Which is not what I am. I want a case where even after logging out or probably I login to another user. I can still use the cookie and access the previous user. Please help me